# What is the difference between "analysed" and "analyzed"?

Tags: meaning

In a dictionary, I saw it gives the same meaning for **analyzed** and **analysed**.
However, In some cases I saw that they used "**were analyzed**" and in others it was "**were analysed**".

Could you please help me to understand the basic difference in those words?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They both have the same meaning. **"Analyse"** is much more common in British English and **"analyze"** is the American and Canadian spelling of the same word. This is also true about these words:

- analysing/analyzing
- analyser/analyzer
- analysed/analyzed

They all come from the noun **"analysis"** which is the corresponding noun in all varieties of English.

Comment: Canadian English has both spellings. Our primary spelling is *analyze*, but *analyse* is also used and accepted. We use both American and British spelling, and things can get a bit complicated . . .

Answer (score 2):

Please also note that even publishers and editors in Britain who use the "-ize" and "-ization" endings (organize, organization) instead of the (slightly) more common "-ise" and "-isation" endings (organise, organisation) still prefer "analyse," "paralyse, "catalyse" and so on for words with an -lys-.

Answer (score 1):

Analyse/analyse is one of a number of words which are spelled with an -se ending in British English, and a -yze ending in American English. Both are correct, and neither is 'wrong', in American and British, but -ze is the majority usage in American English, and -se is the majority usage in British English. People in America or Britain who are unfamiliar with usage statistics sometimes insist that the minority usage in their region is 'wrong'.

[British and American spelling](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/spelling/british-and-spelling)